# default picklist values magick

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, record-type

I have a strange one. Org has an object Test_Object__c with a picklist field Status__c and record types.
Default value is set on each record type and profiles are configured to default record type xType.
A service utility class creates Test_Object__c without specifying record type and status__c
Now everything  works like charm(all default values as expected) when the service was called from triggers. It still works as expected when I debug it in IDE but when the call comes from a controller and VisualForce **only the record type is set**. The picklist is null without default value.
here is what I see in debug logs after insert

```
 SOQL =[SELECT Status__c FROM Test_Object__c WHERE id in :newToInsert]

1)VForce (Test_Object__c:{Id=a2H11000001RfS2EAK, RecordTypeId=012110000005Db8AAE})
2)scrip from IDE (Test_Object__c:{Id=a2H11000001RfS7EAK,Status__c=Awaiting})
```

Could someone explain the difference? The object doesn't appear in VF page at all.

Comment: How is your controller constructing the new SObject? If you want to create a new SObject in APEX that has default values populated in fields you will need to use the `SObjectType.newSObject` method (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#apex_Schema_SObjectType_newSObject_3).

Comment: Never seen it in examples. What's the point of default values if you have to set them? The funny part is it has default values are set when I construct it the normal way and call it from API. Why is creation context aware? Controller does not create the objects nor do they appear on the page. It just passes a string to the service that handles creation.